# Insert HTML Email into page safely

Tags: javascript, html, email

I am working in an environment that layers the dom, and so restricts access to things like iframes. I need to display the contents of an html email on the page (obtained from an email API) and I want to do so safely and correctly.

The issues I see are:

- Security -- disabling risky elements like script tags Since I am
  going to insert just the body,
- I have to pull any style tags from the head
- Since it is email, I have to be able to replace the embedded image references for with actual images (like base64 encoded data type images)

Am I missing anything? This is surely something people do a lot, so is there a library that will take am html email and sanitize it and correct it for inserting into an element in an existing page?

Comment: Not that I think this is irrelevant on SO, but you might want to ask at https://security.stackexchange.com/